# Thresholding a data frame without removing values

Tags: r, dataframe, scatter-plot

I have a data frame that consisting of a non-unique identifier (ID) and measures of some property of the objects within that ID, something like this:

```
ID   Sph
 A   1.0 
 A   1.2
 A   1.1     
 B   0.5     
 B   1.8    
 C   2.2    
 C   1.1    
 D   2.1    
 D   3.0
```

First, I get the number of instances of each ID as X using `table(df$ID)`, i.e. `A=3`, `B=2` ,`C=2` and `D=2`. Next, I would like to apply a threshold in the "Sph" category after getting the number of instances, limiting to rows where the `Sph` value exceeds the threshold. With threshold 2.0, for instance, I would use `thold=df[df$Sph>2.0,]`. Finally I would like to replace the `ID` column with the `X` value that I computed using `table` above. For instance, with a threshold of 1.1 in the "Sph" columns I would like the following output:

```
ID   Sph    
 3   1.0    
 2   1.8    
 2   2.2    
 2   2.1    
 2   3.0
```

In other words, after using `table()` to get an x value corresponding to the number of times an ID has occurred, say 3, I would like to then assign that number to every value in that ID, Y, that is over some threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies in your question and you didn't give a reproducible example, however here's my attempt.

I like to use the dplyr library, in this case I had to break out an sapply, maybe someone can improve on my answer.

Here's the short version:

```
library(dplyr)
#your data
x <- data.frame(ID=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",2),rep("C",2),rep("D",2)),Sph=c(1.0,1.2,1.1,0.5,1.8,2.2,1.1,2.1,3.0),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#lookup table
y <- summarise(group_by(x,ID), IDn=n())

#fill in original table
x$IDn <- sapply(x$ID,function(z) as.integer(y[y$ID==z,"IDn"]))

#filter for rows where Sph greater or equal to 1.1
x <- x %>% filter(Sph>=1.1)

#done
x
```

And here's the longer version with explanatory output:

```
> library(dplyr)
> #your data
> x <- data.frame(ID=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",2),rep("C",2),rep("D",2)),Sph=c(1.0,1.2,1.1,0.5,1.8,2.2,1.1,2.1,3.0),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> x
  ID Sph
1  A 1.0
2  A 1.2
3  A 1.1
4  B 0.5
5  B 1.8
6  C 2.2
7  C 1.1
8  D 2.1
9  D 3.0
> 
> #lookup table
> y <- summarise(group_by(x,ID), IDn=n())
> y
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  ID IDn
1  A   3
2  B   2
3  C   2
4  D   2
> 
> #fill in original table
> x$IDn <- sapply(x$ID,function(z) as.integer(y[y$ID==z,"IDn"]))
> x
  ID Sph IDn
1  A 1.0   3
2  A 1.2   3
3  A 1.1   3
4  B 0.5   2
5  B 1.8   2
6  C 2.2   2
7  C 1.1   2
8  D 2.1   2
9  D 3.0   2
> 
> #filter for rows where Sph greater or equal to 1.1
> x <- x %>% filter(Sph>=1.1)
> 
> #done
> x
  ID Sph IDn
1  A 1.2   3
2  A 1.1   3
3  B 1.8   2
4  C 2.2   2
5  C 1.1   2
6  D 2.1   2
7  D 3.0   2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You seemed to have understood exactly what I was looking for and it worked well. I'm curious though what were the inconsistencies that were sources of confusion in my question?

Comment: Sure, if you take a look at the top question tagged [r] you will see that it is 'How to make a great R reproducible example?'  I highly recommend this thread. You will get more answers if the original data are copy-paste into an r terminal. Also one inconsistency I remember is that you mentioned filtering for a threshold of 1.1 and above, however in the resulting table there is a 1.0. I cannot remember any others at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this in one step after computing `X` and `thold` as you did in your question:

```
X <- table(df$ID)
thold <- df[df$Sph > 1.1,]
thold$ID <- X[as.character(thold$ID)]
thold
#   ID Sph
# 2  3 1.2
# 5  2 1.8
# 6  2 2.2
# 8  2 2.1
# 9  2 3.0
```

Basically you look up the frequency of each ID value in the table `X` that you built.